# How do I disable VS Code "Do you want to synchronize the Java classpath/configuration" once and for all?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

With VS Code, every time I create a new java project and change the pom.xml of it this annoying popup shows up.

[image]

I know I can simply click "Never" though, I really don't want to see it over and over
again.

How do I disable it for all future projects?

Comment: Maybe check the settings of the Java extension. This is not a VS Code core feature.